# Database Design for tracking user flow

Tags: mysql, database-design, django

I want to design a user tracking system between different tables/models. I want to track the user's progress. There is a Module table which is related to sections and sections are related to sub-sections. Each sub-section can relate to different independent tables. The independent tables store different items (slides, videos, texts) which the user can go through in a linear flow just like a Coursera course. The flow will be predetermined by us but can be changed by us. So, the linear flow between the sub-sections can't be hardcoded. I also need to keep track of the user's progress through these sub-sections.

**For Example:**

*A sub-section can point to game table where the user_info, game_score, game_completion_date_time will be stored or there might be case where the sub-section is pointing to slides table storing slide_text, slide_url and user_info.*

I want to keep track of changes in those table so what should be my approach. Below i have posted an image in which i am approaching to the problem.

**EDIT :**

I want to track the user's progress.

A module is a collection of sections.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say *I want to design a user tracking system*, you want to track **what** about users, their progress? ~ *There is a Module table*, please define **Module**, it can mean many different things to a DBA.

Comment: Hi @Mukul it seems you are creating something very ambitious. Please consider taking help from a friend programmer or hiring a developer. Your efforts and tenacity show in the detailed diagrams you posted but there's a lot of technical misunderstanding here

Comment: @RinkyPinku I have updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, please note some technical difficulties: **1.** it's not advisable to store logic (game rules) in a table, that is the coding part not DB part (see `business logic`). **2.** keeping track of changes in table is pushing the limits of current RDBMS technology, you need more

Comment: I understand you may not want to disclose your whole idea but you can contact me if you need